# Android FragmentPagerAdapter findViewById

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I have a Layout which load a FragmentPagerAdapter with 3 Pages.

Simple problem, I can't find any View with findViewById, and I have been searching around for 2 days can't find the solution for this :(

Did I miss anything here?

Any good example to follow?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Dear All, I finally know my mistakes. Fragments are created much later than any other views :(

Comment: The findViewById method belongs to the activity. Fragments have a different lifecycle that is not neccesarly tied up to the activity lifecycle.

Fragment views are not accesible from the activity.